# Laravel - Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

```
@foreach ($wishItems as $wishItem)
    <?php $products = Product::find($wishItem->product_id)->get(); ?>
    @foreach($products as $product)
        @if($product->id == $wishItem->product_id)
            Name: <a href="{{ URL::route('product', $product->id) }}"> {{ $product->title }} </a><br>
            Price: {{ $product->price }} &euro;<br>
            <hr>
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

`$wishItems` is var that is sent to this view and it is ok... **`$products = Product::find($wishItem->product_id)->get();`** here I have problem.. I got error: **`Call to a member function get() on a non-object`** .... I tried to replace **`$wishItem->product_id`** with number for example **`3`** [it exists in DB] but again same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what you really want is:

```
@foreach ($wishItems as $wishItem)
    <?php $product = Product::find($wishItem->product_id); ?>
    Name: <a href="{{ URL::route('product', $product->id) }}"> {{ $product->title }} </a><br>
    Price: {{ $product->price }} &euro;<br>
    <hr>
@endforeach
```

Your `$wishItem` really just refer to a single product, thus eliminating the need for you to query a collection, and do a loop.

Comment: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Does it throw you the error on `$wishItem->product_id` or from `$product`.

Comment: from product... I also tried to replace  $wishItem->product_id  with number but it was the same

Comment: Try `Product::findOrFail($wishItem->product_id)` or your number, if that fails, it literally means the product with that ID can't be found

Comment: I got it... Yeah... I wishlist table I had product_id 3... and in products table I havent got it... :D thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a WishItem and Product model

```
class WishItem extends Eloquent {

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Product');
    }

}
```

In your view

```
$product = $wishItem->product;
```

More info:

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage

Comment: when I remove get I got this: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()